#  how to convert RGB value to hexadecimal value with alpha like (0xFFFFFFFF)?

Tags: android

I have RGB integer value (ex:00255), i want to convert into this format 0XFF0000FF .I used this part of code,

```
int intColor=00255;
String hexColor = String.format("0x%08X", (0xFFFFFFFF & intColor));
```

But i got transparent color.please help me

Comment: `00255` is an Octal Number. Is that *really* what you expect?

Comment: that octal number convert into 0xFF0000FF.it is easy to convert into #0000FF using String.format("#%06X", (0xFFFFFF & rgb color))

Comment: `00255` != `255`: that's all I'm trying to say.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you have an RGB color white : FFFFFF

0x + ?? + FFFFFF will be the final format where ?? is the alpha transparency FF means totally opaque 00 means totally transparent

Opaque white  :0xFFFFFFFF

Transparent White : 0x00FFFFFF

Comment: suppose  this is rgb color 25520147 and hexadecimal is ff1493. Here just add ff before like 0xffff1493.

Comment: Yes to hexadecimal color ff1493 add 0xff if you want total opaque color

Comment: I have string like String hex="803BB9FF"; and i want to covert this into int color=0x803BB9FF please help