# What does the parts of four part hex color mean?

Tags: colors, hex

I have seen color specifications like

```
0x008080FF
```

What do these parts mean? I only know of hexadecimal color codes for RGB values (maybe also RGBA, but this doesn't seem to be the case).

An example can be seen [here](http://code.google.com/p/vba-rerecording/issues/detail?id=55). It seems that 0x00FFFFFF means cyan. Why is this the case? What color model do they use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, this representation goes back a while, and isn't used much in the more common programming languages.

So let's consider this one: `0xFF447799`

- `0x`: This indicates that this represents a hexadecimal value (in many
  cases, this is replaced by the `#` character)
- next 2 digits (`FF`): This controls the opacity, in this case 100% (or FF)
- next 2 digits (`44`): This represents RR, the amount of red color
- next 2 digits (`77`): This represents GG, the amount of green color
- next 2 digits (`99`): This represents BB, the amount of blue color

In a lot of current languages, you would just see the RGB or ARGB variations of this representation. So current technologies cope with hexadecimal values without the `0x` having to tell them.

Apparently, this representation [isn't valid in HTML and CSS](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_colors_legal.asp).

See also [how to convert RGB value to hexadecimal value with alpha like (0xFFFFFFFF)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8633214/how-to-convert-rgb-value-to-hexadecimal-value-with-alpha-like-0xffffffff)

Comment: I was also considering ARGB (although I have never seen this). But I am puzzled by the above mentioned definition of 0x00FFFFFF as Cyan. Also I have seen somewhere that 0x00FF8000 should be some dark blue. That would'nt fit to ARGB.

Comment: I think it might depend on the environment you're working on. 00FFFF is cyan indeed, so in that case, the last 2 digits would mean they tell what opacity it is. Check this msdn post, it in that case, the opacity is are the first 2 digits, so it really differs depending on environment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc543931.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I think this is an [ARGB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RGBA_color_space#ARGB_(word-order)) value. This means that the first byte is the alpha channel.

For example, 00 is fully transparent.