# Dynamically add 0x prefix to int in Java

Tags: java, hex, literals

```
int i = 16777215;

void draw(int color) {


}
```

Lets say void draw expects the color to start with the 0x prefix like so

```
draw(0x16777215)
```

If I try this it throws a syntax error

```
draw(0x + i)

Invalid hex literal number
```

int i cannot contain the 0x part, it needs to be dynamically added

thanks

Comment: I think you misunderstand the purpose of `0x`. It's for integer literals.

Comment: 16777215 (decimal) and 0x16777215 (hex) are REALLY different values. You need to figure out which one do you want.

Answer (score 19):

`0x1234` is just another way of writing an integer value. For instance, `0xff` and `255` are exactly the same thing. `draw(0x16777215)` and `draw(376926741)` are identical calls. At the bytecode level, there's not *any* difference. The only difference is to how it appears to a human reading the code; sometimes it's easier to think in terms of bytes, which are easily expressed in hex.

If a number starts with `0x`, it means the rest of the digits are interpreted as hex. Instead of `0x16777215`, I'm guessing you wanted `16777215` (without the `0x`), which is also `0xFFFFFF`.

The [Oracle tutorial on primitive datatypes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) has a bit more information (and more authority than I do :) ).

To demonstrate that it's all the same under the hood, you can look at some disassembled code. Consider this class:

```
public class Hexes {
  public static int alpha = 0x16777215;
  public static int beta = 376926741;
}
```

Running `javap -c Hexes` after compiling `Hexes.java` will show you what's happening under the hood:

```
Compiled from "Hexes.java"
public class Hexes {
  public static int alpha;

  public static int beta;

  public Hexes();
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: return

  static {};
    Code:
       0: ldc           #2                  // int 376926741
       2: putstatic     #3                  // Field alpha:I
       5: ldc           #2                  // int 376926741
       7: putstatic     #4                  // Field beta:I
      10: return
}
```

The block labeled `static {}` is the class' static initializer, where `alpha` and `beta` are set. Note that the two fields (alpha and beta) are both assigned the same int value. If you were to write a short program to print the values out, you'd see the same value for each:

```
public class HexesPrinter {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(Hexes.alpha);
        System.out.println(Hexes.beta);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
376926741
376926741
```

Comment: I really don't see how disassembling some code adds to your answer.  The question is really all about Java syntax and semantics.  If you need supporting evidence, either write a program that produces some output ... or cite a reputable source like the relevant part of the Oracle Java Tutorials or the JLS.

Comment: The purpose of the disassembly was to show that, as far as the compiled program is concerned, both values are just `int 376926741`. But I'll add a citation, too -- good suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

Just pass `i`.  There is no such thing as a method that expects a number that starts with `0x`.  If it takes an `int`, then it will take any `int`, specified as a hexadecimal literal with `0x` or not.

Also, be careful.  `0x16777215` is a different number than `16777215`.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you need this:

```
Integer.valueOf(String.valueOf(i), 16)
```

Comment: I have string like String hex="803BB9FF"; and i want to covert this into int color=0x803BB9FF please help

Comment: long color = Long.valueOf(hex,16); // hex your string

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand first the difference between specifying base 10 numbers and base 16 numbers (hex) in Java. As others stated `0x` is a prefix to a number that says it's in base 16 (hex).

It's useful to specify colors in hex notation because they have components (Alpha, R, G, B), which are not obvious when you put them in base 10. See this answer for more details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8633244/1168342